# PHP Rand() not working same result in different rand () variables..

Tags: php, random

I have this code:

```
$im = glob($directory . "*.html");
$last = end($im );
$hongi= rand(2, $last);
```

This is not working because rand () expects parameter 2 to works and this parameter its an string.

It is possible making rand () works with a variable parameter?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:

Better explain this code:

I have thousands of files and each file names is a number.

Im extracting the names of these files in an array.

Im getting the last value using end ().

Use $hongi to get a random value between "2" and the last value of the array.

**So the random value will never exceed the last value of the array.**

I have a really basic error because Im getting a filepath like this:

../motor/sector1/17001400300120110111900.html
../motor/sector1/17001400300120110111920.html
../motor/sector1/17001400300120110111930.html
../motor/sector1/17001400300120110111950.html

so Im doing this

```
$im = glob($directory . "*.html");
$last = end($im );
$numl = substr($last,24,-5);
$hongi= rand(2, $num1);
```

Thats fine, but then Im do this:

```
 $hongi= rand(2, $num1);
 $hongi1= rand(2,$num1);
 $hongi2= rand(2, $num1);
$hongi3= rand(2, $num1);
 $hongi4= rand(2, $num1);
```

But all "hongi" variables are the same result. Why?

Comment: how are you going to take a random from a file name...

Comment: can u be more specific ?

Comment: You want the last file in a possibly sorted differently than you expected list to be the max bound of a random number?

Comment: @alex I'm assuming he wants to get a random index for $im? in that case $last should just be count($im);

Comment: @kennypu I have thousands of files Im taking random file names from that because I need it.

Comment: @Kennypu Why does the OP's code start at `2` then? Not sure either...

Comment: Probably doesn't understand `rand()` function ?

Comment: so yeah, as I said he just wants to get a random index.

Comment: I think he needs `shuffle` but I can't tell what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: Guys Im just edit my question explaining my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1642423 try the answer I just posted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to get a random filename, first of all, you're using `rand()` incorrectly. it takes 2 integers between min and max. the value you gave for max is a filepath, not a integer. You want the `count()` of $im, and use that:

```
$im = glob($directory . "*.html");
$last = count($im);
$hongi= rand(2, $last - 1); // -1 because arrays start at 0
$random_file = $im[$hongi];
```

Comment: Yes, I know that is a filepath but that's my question: how to chance this second parameter so can get a variable value instead and integer. Im gonna try your solution.

Comment: @kennypu is this more efficient to randomly pick a index number instead of shuffling the array? Just a side curiosity

Comment: @Dave good question, I'd assume using shuffle() is faster, but if you'd want to keep the original array structure for whatever reason, using shuffle() will screw that up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to do a random choice using strings you need to put them in an array and do Array shuffle.

```
shuffle($array_of_filenames);
echo $array_of_filenames[0];
```

More examples:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Thanks, but Im doing a random my question is: how change the second random parameter so I can give a variable instead an integer.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the value of $last would be ?

Comment: Echo $num1 before the rands to see what the value has.. need to be sure its got the correct data.

Comment: Im not getting anything from that echo I don't know why.

Comment: Because `$im` is not an array I'm guessing but i don't know what `glob` does.

Comment: do `print_r($im);` see what output you get

Answer (score -1):

Typecasting may help:

```
$hongi= rand(2, (int)$last);
```

Comment: the value of $last is a file path, not an integer. thus it won't do whatever he's trying to do.

Comment: Good call. I'll leave my answer here as an example of what happens when you jump the gun. :) Downvote me to oblivion. lol.